# How do I unlock the bonus moon levels?

Tags: splitter-critters

On the level select screen of Splitter Critters, there are five visible moons. [According to App Unwrapper](http://www.appunwrapper.com/2017/01/26/splitter-critters-walthrough-guide-and-solutions/), each moon has three unlockable bonus levels. However, when I select a moon on the menu, I'm not able to view any of the bonus levels.

How do I unlock the bonus moon levels in Splitter Critters?

[image: Five moons on level select screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bonus moons will unlock after you've completed all the main planets.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find this question?